# Default value for Checkboxes from Category

Tags: web8.5, schema, keyword, categories

I'm currently using "Values to be selected from a list", and "Category", with List type being `Checkboxes`.

My Categories list has 5 items in them, I'd like to have 3 of them selected by default (as 3 of them are commonly used).

I seem to be only be able to select **one** of the Keywords as my default, is there any way to have more than one selected?

I'm on Tridion 8.5

Comment: Sorry to dissapoint you but no. Default value is only one, and its so by design of product.

Comment: Request a product enhancement or extend it - as Marko states - it's 'by design' (although I've never understood why)

Comment: The ability to set such defaults for a new Component (Presentation) is a feature only in Experience Manager's Content Types. I don't think there's a _technical_ "why" as to why this isn't a feature in the CME and Schema designer, though aligning XPM and the CME a bit more is something we're looking at in future versions of Tridion Sites.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to dissapoint you but no. Default value is only one, and its so by design of product.

Comment: True, though Content Types in XPM which can set _any_ defaults for any fields. I'd argue this is an existing feature, just not helpful for users in the Content Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

The default value which can be set on Component creation is only a single value. If you need multiple values, you can use an event handler to set additional default values.

Please keep in mind you need to set these only once so you need to choose the correct event and do some checks if this is indeed the moment to load defaults.

There used to be a TOM event named `OnSchemaGetInstanceDataPost`, I believe this was the Schema being read for the initial creation of a Component, the documentation (https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-DF367267-7648-4137-BBAB-C9FF14D28D11) states that in the .NET event handlers this event trigger does not exist. But you can approximate it by the combination of the Subject `Component`, the Type `SaveEventArgs` and the Phase `Initiated`. So that is a nudge in the richt direction, maybe somebody else in the community can add a more detailed answer.

Comment: If I were to extend this, I'd rely on either the Content Types set in a Publication or at least "prototype" Components to set and manage the defaults for a flexible approach (akin to the standard Page Types that DXA ships with).

Comment: Nice option @Alvin, but one that unfortunately only works in XPM.

Comment: I”m not sure why the TOM migration docs say that there is no TOM.NET equivalent for Schema Instance Data. I’m pretty sure there is one and that is indeed the place where you can customize the generation of default values.